# Programmatically equalize windows inside a function

Tags: vim

I've got the following vimscript function:

```
function! WindowCommand(cmd)
    execute a:cmd
    if !g:golden_ratio_enabled
       normal <C-w>=
    endif
endfunction
```

And I use it like so:

```
map <space>w/ :call WindowCommand(':vs')<cr>
```

It's supposed to equalize the windows, but only if `g:golden_ratio_enabled` is 0, otherwise it should do nothing.

It doesn't work, though, and I'm not sure why, because the following DOES work:

```
map <space>w/ :vs<cr><C-w>=
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple fixes. Thankfully, the fix is really simple

For whatever reason, `normal <C-w>foo` does not work; You must use `wincmd` instead. From `:h wincmd`

```
                        *:winc* *:wincmd*
These commands can also be executed with ":wincmd":

:[count]winc[md] {arg}
        Like executing CTRL-W [count] {arg}.  Example: >
            :wincmd j
        Moves to the window below the current one.
        This command is useful when a Normal mode cannot be used (for
        the |CursorHold| autocommand event).  Or when a Normal mode
        command is inconvenient.
        The count can also be a window number.  Example: >
            :exe nr . "wincmd w"
        This goes to window "nr".
```

So in this case, you should do

```
wincmd =
```

Alternatively, you could enter a literal `<C-w>` character, by typing `<C-v><C-w>`. In your vim session, this character will be displayed as `^W`.

Answer (score 1):

To execute actions with `<notation>`, use instead:

```
:exe "normal \<notation>"
```

I use it a lot to debug mappings.

But in this case, prefer indeed `wincmd`.